# Proof of infinitude of primes using Wilson's theorem

Tags: number-theory, analysis

Can we prove the infinitude of primes using Wilson's theorem ?

That is ; can we prove the following statement? :

$xy-(x-1)!-1 = 0$

Above equation has infinitely many lattice point solutions.

EDIT:

As the comments I'm seeing I will explain in detail the question :

(1)Assume that you don't know whether there are infinitely or finitely many primes

(2) Now consider if for any integer $x$ there is an integer $y$ that satisfies the above equation then $x$ is prime (Wilson's theorem - No need of infinitude of prime in any sense)

(3) Are there infinitely many pairs $(x,y)$ such that they belong to class of positive integers ?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking whether one can show that $xy-(x-1)!-1 = 0$  has infinitely many lattice point solutions without using Wilson's theorem?

Comment: This question has an unusual wording, it sounds like you are trying to prove there are infinitely many primes (for that, Wilson's theorem is overkill).  On the other hand the question seems to (also?) deal with integer solutions to $xy-(x-1)! - 1 =0$. However, the statement of Wilson's theorem itself immediately implies there are infinitely many integer solutions (just consider the primes!).  [I don't know what you mean by a "lattice point"  but I assume you are really looking for integer solutions.]

Comment: @Michael yes I'm looking for integer solutions . Consider this imagine we don't know whether or not there are infinitely many primes , then again Wilson's theorem works . So my question is can we prove that there are infinitely many integer solutions to the equation and hence infinitely many primes?

Comment: Why not go all the way and ask, if we can prove the Riemann hypothesis to be true, would that enable an alternative proof that there are infinitely many primes? =)

Comment: It seems like a reasonable question: can we prove there are infinitely many $n$ dividing $(n-1)!+1$ without knowing or first proving there are infinitely many primes? Now posted to MathOverflow – you really ought to include a link to that question here.

Comment: As others have commented, the question as stated is trivial, but you meant rather to ask whether that equation can be proved to have infinitely many integer solutions **without** first proving that there are infinitely many primes and invoking Wilson's theorem. Unfortunately, there seems to be no good notion of "proving X without first proving Y". The problem is that a proof of X using Y can usually be tweaked to no longer obviously use Y but to use the essential idea from the proof of Y. So you'd need to specify what counts as "cheating" by indirectly using Y. Specifying that is hard.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson thank you for support , sir . Very few are trying to understand the question and fewer are really understanding it . It only seem elementary and vague but it's not . I've deleted the question from overflow as it is put on hold . But question seems perfectly reasonable to me .

Comment: @A.S.A. The question is reasonable, but where is the motivation for this alternative proof ? I am sceptical that such a proof exists, but this is just an intuitive guess.

Comment: @Peter there are papers by Bombieri and Pila , and JJ Huang about integral points on and near space curve but they only give upper bounds in very general and sometimes very special cases . This is my motivation for thinking in this way .

Comment: Gamma function on positive domain is convex but the problem is Gamma function is hypertranscendental and dilation of it is hard

Comment: At least can we get an estimate for integer points close to above equation using methods given by Huxley and others ?

Comment: Edit for comment : upper bounds for number of Lattice points up to given abscissa or ordinate .

Comment: @ Peter I'm also equally sceptical but Even though this seems not useful ; if such a result could be attained it will give a generalized platform for every major open prime number problem , Just think , So I asked .